# Delete any special character using Sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have yet another list of subdomain. I want to remove any `Wildcard` subdomain which include these special characters:

```
()!&$#*+?
```

Mostly, the data are prefixly random. Also, could be middle. Here's some sample of output data

```
(www.imgur.com
***************diet.blogspot.com
*-1.gbc.criteo.com
------------------------------------------------------------i.imgur.com
```

This has been quite an inconvenience while scanning through the list. As always, I'm trying sed to fix it:

```
sed -i "/[!()#$&?+]/d" foo.txt ###Didn't work
sed -i "/[\!\(\)\#\$\&\?\+]/d" ###Escaping char didn't work
```

Performing commands above still result in an `unchanged` list and the file still on original state. I'm thinking that; to fix this is to pipe series of `sed` command in order to remove it one by one:

```
cat foo.txt | sed -e "/!/d" -e "/#/d" -e "/\*/d" -e "/\$/d" -e "/(/d" -e "/)/d" -e "/+/d" -e "/\'/d" -e "/&/d" >> foo2.txt
cat foo.txt | sed -e "/\!/d" | sed -e "/\#/d" | sed -e "/\*/d" | sed -e "/\$/d" | sed -e "/\+/d" | sed -e "/\'/d" | sed -e "/\&/d" >> foo2.txt
```

If escaping all special char doesn't work, it must've been my false logic. Also tried with `/g` still doesn't increase my luck.

As a side note: I don't want `-` to be deleted as some valid subdomain can have `-` character:

```
line-apps.com
line-apps-beta.com
line-apps-rc.com
line-apps-dev.com
```

Any help would be cherished.

Comment: It may be that the shell is playing a part here - try using single quotes to encapsulate your sed commands rather than double.

Comment: That's it! thank you for the reminder, i'm missing the part where that's my problem. I'm gonna train myself to always use single-quotation. Thanks really....

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: What you're trying to remove aren't all `wildcard` characters btw., nor is it any other standard set, it's just some specific list of characters you want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you're trying to do in your answer (which adds `[` and `]` and more to the set of characters in your question) would be:

```
sed '/[][!?+,#$&*() ]/d'
```

or just:

```
grep -v '[][!?+,#$&*() ]'
```

Per POSIX to include `]` in a bracket expression it must be the first character otherwise it indicates the end of the bracket expression.

Consider printing lines you want instead of deleting lines you do not want, though, e.g.:

```
grep '^[[:alnum:]_.-]$' file
```

to print lines that only contain letters, numbers, underscores, dashes, and/or periods.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/[[:punct:]]/d' input_file
```

This should delete all lines with special characters, however, it would help if you provided sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, already add some sample. Is using the above command will also delete ```-``` character? I hope not.

Comment: @Xav why not try it and see: `echo '-' | sed '/[[:punct:]]/d'`?